# Using PhantomJS for screenshots after logging in

Tags: javascript, asp.net, phantomjs

I am attempting to use PhantomJs to crawl our ASP.Net web app and take screenshots of a list of pages defined in a simple text file of URLs. I have been able to get it working fine for pages not behind the log-in wall, but can't seem to get my PhantomJs instance to get authenticated. Log messages show that I'm doing things in the right order with my two interval functions - any ideas how to make sure I'm logged in first?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    system = require('system');

var content = '',
    f = null,
    lines = null,
    pages =null,
    destinations = null,
    eol = system.os.name == 'windows' ? "\r\n" : "\n";

//read in a line break separated list of urls   
//page at index 0 is the login page
try {
    f = fs.open(".\\urls.txt", "r");
    content = f.read();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

if (f) {
    f.close();
}

if (content) {
    lines = content.split(eol);
    pages = new Array();
    destinations = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        var pageName = lines[i].substring(lines[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        pages[i] = pageName;    
        destinations[i] = ".\\NewScreenShot\\" + pageName + '.png';
    }
}

console.log('Pages found: ' + pages.length);


var page = require('webpage').create();


var loginIndex = 0;
var loginInProgress = false;
var loginSteps = [
  function() {
    //Enter Credentials
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("txtusername").value = "ausername@mysite.com";
        document.getElementById("txtpassword").value ="12345678";      
        return;
    });
  }, 
  function() {
    //Login
    page.evaluate(function() {
      var arr = document.getElementById("form1");
      var i;
       for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].getAttribute('method') == "POST") {
          arr[i].submit();
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }
];

var LoadPage = function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && pageindex < pages.length) {
        console.log("image " + (pageindex + 1) + " of " + lines.length);
        page.open(lines[pageindex]);
    }
    if (pageindex == lines.length) {
        console.log("<< Image render complete! >>");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}


//PNG RENDER
var pageindex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;
var interval = setInterval(LoadPage, 500);

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    if(pageindex == 0)  {
        loginInProgress = true;
    }
    console.log('page ' + (pageindex + 1) + ' load started');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;   

    if(pageindex == 0)
    {
        loginInProgress = false;
        console.log("stopping page interval");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    page.evaluate( 
      function () {
        var scaleVal = "scale("+arguments[0] || '1.0'+")";
        document.body.style.webkitTransform = scaleVal;
      }     
    );
    console.log("rendering:" + destinations[pageindex]);
    page.render(destinations[pageindex]); // RENDER PAGE //

    if (pageindex == 0){
       var loginInterval = setInterval(function() {
          if (!loginInProgress && typeof loginSteps[loginIndex] == "function") {
            console.log("login step: " + loginIndex )
            loginSteps[loginIndex]();
            loginIndex++;
          }
          if (typeof loginSteps[loginIndex] != "function") {
            console.log("stopping login interval");
            clearInterval(loginInterval);

            console.log("starting page interval");
            setInterval(LoadPage, 500);
          }
        }, 50);
    }

    pageindex++;
}
```

Comment: Figured out an answer but StackOverflow won't let me post it until tomorrow. Rats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was form submit vs button click. working code below:

```
var urlsLocation = "C:\\PhantomJs\\urls.txt";
var newScreenshotFolder = "C:\\PhantomJs\\NewScreenShot\\";

var fs = require('fs'),
    system = require('system');

var content = '',
    f = null,
    lines = null,
    pages =null,
    destinations = null,
    eol = system.os.name == 'windows' ? "\r\n" : "\n";

//read in a return separated list of urls   
try {
    f = fs.open(urlsLocation, "r");
    content = f.read();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

if (f) {
    f.close();
}

if (content) {
    lines = content.split(eol);
    pages = new Array();
    destinations = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        var pageName = lines[i].substring(lines[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        pages[i] = pageName;    
        destinations[i] = newScreenshotFolder + pageName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/g, "") + '.png';
    }
}

console.log('Pages found: ' + pages.length);


var page = require('webpage').create();


var loginIndex = 0;
var loginInProgress = false;
var loginCompleted = false;
var loginSteps = [
  function() {
    //Enter Credentials
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("txtusername").value = "testemail@gmail.com";
        document.getElementById("txtpassword").value = "12345678";      
        return;
    });
  }, 
  function() {
    //Login
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("btnLogin").click();           
          return;
    });
  }
];

var LoadPage = function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && pageindex < pages.length) {
        console.log("image " + (pageindex + 1) + " of " + lines.length);
        page.open(lines[pageindex]);
    }
    if (pageindex == lines.length) {
        console.log("<< Image render complete! >>");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}


//PNG RENDER
var pageindex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;
var interval = setInterval(LoadPage, 500);

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    if(pageindex == 0)  {
        loginInProgress = true;
    }
    console.log('page ' + (pageindex + 1) + ' load started');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;   

    if(pageindex == 0)
    {
        loginInProgress = false;
        console.log("stopping page interval");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    page.evaluate( 
      function () {
        var scaleVal = "scale("+arguments[0] || '1.0'+")";
        document.body.style.webkitTransform = scaleVal;
      }     
    );
    console.log("rendering:" + destinations[pageindex]);
    page.render(destinations[pageindex]); // RENDER PAGE //

    if (pageindex == 0){
       var loginInterval = setInterval(function() {
          if (!loginInProgress && typeof loginSteps[loginIndex] == "function") {
            console.log("login step: " + loginIndex )
            loginSteps[loginIndex]();
            loginIndex++;
          }
          if (typeof loginSteps[loginIndex] != "function") {
            console.log("stopping login interval");
            clearInterval(loginInterval);

            console.log("starting page interval");
            setInterval(LoadPage, 1000);
          }
        }, 50);
    }

    pageindex++;
}
```